# Methods for counting HTML tags in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am learning to build a web scraping program in VBA that will dump event info into Excel.

I am working with an HTML code that looks like this:

```
<div class="artist-box-headliner">...
<div class="artist-box-support">...
    <div id="tfly-more-1" style="display: none;">
<div class="artist-box-support">...
    <div id="tfly-more-2" style="display: none;">
<div class="artist-box-support">...
    <div id="tfly-more-3" style="display: none;">
<div class="artist-box-support">...
    <div id="tfly-more-4" style="display: none;">
```

Since each event will have a different number of support artists I would like to count how many times "artist-box-support" is mentioned. What method can I use to do this?

Alternatively, is it more efficient to find a way to just grab the # in the last "tfly-more-#"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Get the html source code using .document() and save it in String variable, lets say 'strHtmlCode'

Step 2: Calculate the occurance of the required string (i.e "artist-box-support") in String variable strHtmlCode using VBA string functions.

Here is the nested if functions i created to count the occurance of one string in another:
numberOfOccurance = Len(strHtmlCode) - Len(Replace(strHtmlCode, "artist-box-support", ""))

Answer (score 2):

If using IE for example

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelectorAll(".artist-box-support").Length
```

`querySelectorAll` will apply the CSS selector of `.artist-box-support`, elements with className `artist-box-support`, and return a nodeList. The number of elements retrieved can be obtained from the `.Length` property of the `nodeList` remembering it is 0 indexed.